# Doesn't redirect_to page on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, redirect

On success, the form submits remotely and correctly loads index.js.erb (Life is well)

However on error (the else) nothing happens. What I want to do, on error load a different file or add logic to index.js.erb. However, it just fails and doesn't load.

Error
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)** I know receive a 406 Error, after implementing the rescue

(*I understand that is because it doesn't find an event, but how do I ensure it loads my index.js.erb- so I can in turn display a modal notifying the user* )

Events Controller

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event = Event.find_by_event_code(params[:checkin])
      format.html { redirect_to @event, success: "You have found your event" }
      format.js
    elsif @event = Event.find_by_speaker_code(params[:checkin])
      format.html { redirect_to @event, success: "Welcome Super User. You have found your event" }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { redirect_to @event, error: "No event by that event code" }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#checkin-popup").remove();
$("#checkin-confirm-popup").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("/events/index.html.erb")) %>")
$('#checkin-confirm-popup').modal('show');
```

button.html

```
<%= simple_form_for @event, remote: true ,:method => 'get' do |e| %>
    <div class="talknumber"><%= text_field_tag :checkin, params[:search] %></div>
  <%= e.button :submit, "Checkin", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

server log

```
Started GET "/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&checkin=1212122&commit=Checkin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-10 11:43:39 -0500
Processing by EventsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "checkin"=>"1212122", "commit"=>"Checkin"}
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "users"."name" FROM "users"
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."event_code" = 1212122 ORDER BY events.created_at ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."speaker_code" = 1212122 ORDER BY events.created_at ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a begin rescue block

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        if @event = Event.find_by_event_code(params[:checkin])
          format.html { redirect_to @event, success: "You have found your event" }
          format.js
        elsif @event = Event.find_by_speaker_code(params[:checkin])
          format.html { redirect_to @event, success: "Welcome Super User. You have found your event" }
          format.js
        end
      rescue
        format.html { redirect_to @event, error: "No event by that event code" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried the begin rescue block.. I now get a 406 error - GET http://localhost:3000/events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&checkin=dawdw12&commit=Checkin 406 (Not Acceptable)

Comment: @RedRory are you familiar with debugger? can you stop the flow in the rescue block and check?

Comment: I installed debugger, and placed it on Line 2, however when I try to "next" through. It carries me into active_record/relation.rb and other high level method and I'm literally "nexting" twenty times and never come to my index action.

Answer (score 0):

If you have calls in your view that reference the `@event` then you need to deal with them. If on the page you've got (say) a form that submits values, then simply making sure that the view is supplied with `@event = Event.new` should suffice. However, probably that's not the case, so you want to rescue at the view stage by providing an alternative value that makes sense within the context of the page if @event is undefined. Something like:

```
<%= @event ? @event : 'No event' %>
```

rather than just

```
<%= @event %>
```

EDIT: new controller code

```
def index
 respond_to do |format|
    if @event = Event.find_by_event_code(params[:checkin])
      format.html { redirect_to @event, success: "You have found your event" }
      format.js
    else 
      if @event = Event.find_by_speaker_code(params[:checkin])
        format.html { redirect_to @event, success: "Welcome Super User. You have found your event" }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @event, error: "No event by that event code" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't really think this is a great way of doing things though. The form should be separated so you get separate params you can query on, specifying that if (say) `params.has_key? :foo` then do something, and vice versa.

```
<%= simple_form_for @event, remote: true ,:method => 'get' do |e| %>
  <div class="talknumber">
    <%= text_field_tag :event_code, params[:search] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :speaker_code, 'value here - I don't know what params[:search is] %>
  </div>
  <%= e.button :submit, "Checkin", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

This way you can say that if `params.has_key? :event_code` is false, then look for `params.has_key? :speaker_code`, and failing that, execute the else branch.

Comment: This came to mind; I temporarily changed my index.js.erb to alert("Test"); So no loading of <% @event %> is happening

Comment: Oh, so `@event` isn't being used anywhere in `index.js.erb`? Remember that your alert will only be fired on the client side, and your server is erroring before then.

Comment: For debugging purposes, I removed everything from index.js.erb and now only calling an alert. (Just trying to get it calling the file on error). No luck. Could if be after my ELSE (Line 10), I'm trying to redirect to "@event"[that we know exist], or is it skipping format.html and going straight to format.js

Comment: Well, you just said that you were checking index.js.erb but there's only setup occurring in the html format block. The js block has nothing to work with.

Comment: Without passing variables or calling :render, I'm not sure Rails will do anything.

Comment: However on success, it correctly calls index.js.erb, and I only have "format.js" in the success block (Line 5)

Comment: It'll only return the js format if you've say, specified a js return with remote: true or it is happening elsewhere. If this were pure ruby, I'd guess implicit return so it's not that. Can you tail your server log and show the request?

Comment: I am using remote:true on form. I've added my server log

Comment: Right, so if you use remote: true it will always call the js response.

Comment: Right, so several things are happening here. The server is loading records based on both event speaker and event code as the logic in the controller is wrong. After that, it's also not rendering anything I think. I'll take a look at your controller code and update my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer, I think modifying the form is probably best and then you should be able to use this to guide you through sorting your `.js.erb` template and routing. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Hey Alex, I looked at the code. However, work flow wise. I want to keep it as one input search for Event / Cospeaker. That aspects work; if I enter a correct event_code I load the page; if I enter the a correct cospeaker_code; I also load the page. It's just nothing loads if I enter a incorrect code - one that isn't event_code OR cospeaker_code